# Pandas: tidy multilevel data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get this dataset into a tidy format in pandas.

[image]

I need to melt/reshape this in such a way as to have one **id** column, one for **Side (Left/Right)**, one for **Section (1/2/3)**, one for **Size** and another for **Distance**:

[image]

I'm quite new to Python (Pandas in particular) and I've tried to follow this example: [Tidy data from multilevel Excel file via pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319532/tidy-data-from-multilevel-excel-file-via-pandas)

However, I'm not fully understanding how to get this done.
Any advice would be very welcome!

EDIT: here's a sample file:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/bc88b005b185c48eee99fd9583483f4720210602112358/b5f691

Comment: My opinion is best share your excel sample data by dropbox, gdocs, wetranswer... because hard to know how is real structure data from picture (and if convert to text also same problem)

Comment: @jezrael just added a wetransfer link to the post with an example file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `MultiIndex` by `header` parameter in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by first and second level, last set names of axis by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and create columns from `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('test_data.xlsx', header=[0,1,2], index_col=0)

df = df.stack([0,1]).rename_axis(index=['id','Side','Section'], columns=None).reset_index()
print (df)
    id   Side  Section  Distance  Size
0   f1   Left        1       234    12
1   f1   Left        2       678   456
2   f1   Left        3      1122   900
3   f1  Right        1      1566  1344
4   f1  Right        2      2010  1788
5   f1  Right        3      2454  2232
6   f2   Left        1       453    33
7   f2   Left        2      1293   873
8   f2   Left        3      2133  1713
9   f2  Right        1      2973  2553
10  f2  Right        2      3813  3393
11  f2  Right        3      4653  4233
```